# Driver signing.Signing Cert does not chain to a Microsoft Root Cert

Tags: driver, code-signing

I'm trying to sign a driver, I have a certificate "Thawte Code Singing CA - G2".I'm doing it this way.
signtool sign / v / t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll / n "CertName" / du www.bla driver.sys
When checking the driver I get this result:
signtool verify / v / d / a / kp driver.sys
Signing Cert does not chain to a Microsoft Root Cert

Maybe I need some sort of cross certificate? if yes then where can I get it and how to specify the parameters for signtool ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you need a cross-certificate.
Please look at this page:
https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&id=SO5565&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1381952841942#

The bottom contains the cross-certificate you require and it should work on CA - G2 even for 64bit drivers.

In any case, you can find a lot of great easily explained information regarding driver signing from MSDN (and especially on cross-certificates):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546234(v=vs.85).aspx